# A car park has 10 empty spaces. 5 cars park in the car park. What is the probability of no two cars being parked next to each other?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been trying to work out the answer to this question, but I don't have a markscheme so I'd like to confirm if I'm correct or not.

I drew out the number of orientations in which no two cars are parked next to each other and found that there are 6 combinations that fit the criteria.

I then found 6/(10C5), which gave me 6/252 or 1/42 as the probability. Is my working/answer correct?

Comment: You are correct in your answer to the question.

Comment: @NewGuy:  They could be in $1,3,6,8,10$ as well, for example

Comment: my mistake i have deleted my comment

Comment: @drhab thank you for confirming ;)

Comment: Presumably, drivers arrive sequentially and each parks in a space chosen *uniformly at random* from the set of empty spaces? If you don't specify a probability distribution, the question of "probability" is not meaningful. You could instead ask a more purely combinatorial question, like "how many possible arrangements of cars are there, and how many arrangements are there in which no two cars are adjacent?".

Comment: About 50%.  Most drivers don't like to park adjacent to another car, so it's a tossup whether the second car will park in a space that permits an alternating pattern of empty and occupied spaces.  If they do, adjacency aversion will take care of the rest.

Comment: In addition, the statement of the question doesn't define that these 10 empty spaces are all adjacent to each other. It could be a car-park that has a total of 1000 spaces, but only 10 are empty, none of which are adjacent. Then the answer is that there is a 100% chance of no two additional cars being parked next to each other.

Comment: @Makyen ...or say the entire car park is ten spaces: is it arranged in two rows of five spaces, one row of ten spaces, or some other setup?

Comment: If we want to complicate things and add a touch of reality (in a maths question?!), it depends on the location of the parking lot, the drivers and the cars.  If it was a supermarket parking lot, each driver would probably want to get as close to the door as possible, therefore skewing the results to have cars park closer. If all 5 cars were hypercars, they'd want to space themselves to avoid damage. At a campsite or beach, we could assume that people in the cars will have stuff they want to get out of their cars easily, so probably more spread out.

Comment: I'll admit I wasn't as clear as I should've been in the question. I simply wrote it out word for word from my textbook. What I should've said is that the spaces are all in a line, side by side. Ignore any external factors which would affect the way in which people park - assume it's a random choice (whether or not a random choice really exists is a whole other debate!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a systematic approach:

Note that the possible patterns must have the form $$0^a\,X\,0^b\,X\,0^c\,X\,0^d\,X\,0^e\,X\,0^f$$

Where $0$ is an empty space, $X$ is a car, $a+b+c+d+e+f=5$ and $b,c,d,e>0$. Letting $b'=b-1,c'=c-1,d'=d-1,e'=e-1$ we see that $a+b'+c'+d'+e'+f=1$ so exactly one of these is non-zero (and that one is equal to $1$).  That translates to $6$ options, confirming your solution.

Comment: Thank you for this; I got the combinations by drawing them out but I didn't know how to show it numerically. This really helps

Comment: Worth noting:  for more complicated set ups (with more spaces, for example), you can still do it this way though it will be harder to simply read off the answer.  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) helps a lot for those problems.

Comment: I think you should specify your pattern is a string, so people don't get confused with an algebraic expression.

Answer (score 2):

Park $5$ cars on $6$ spots -- in $6=\binom{6}{5}$ ways. Add between each car one extra spot and  get a proper parking on $6+4=10$ spots.

Comment: This is a really interesting way of approaching the question. Would this method work for 4 or 3 cars on a 10-space car park?